# How to create Stripe Extension for Visual Studio Code

Tags: api, typescript, visual-studio-code

I wanted to create a Stripe extension for Visual Studio Code but I couldn't show amount value in status bar. I can make it with information windows but when I try to show amount value in status bar, I am getting an error like "statusbar undefined".

Here is my code, waiting for your help thank you

```
import * as vscode from 'vscode';
import * as Stripe from 'Stripe';

// This method is called when your extension is activated. Activation is
// controlled by the activation events defined in package.json.
export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {

    console.log('Congratulations, your extension "Stripe" is now active!');

    // Show Balance
    let showBalance = new StripeBalance();

    context.subscriptions.push(showBalance);

}

class StripeBalance {

    public strip = new Stripe('sk_test_Dvh7P0XJ2NmlWjBokaH7SCSl');
    public shBalance:any = this.strip.balance.retrieve(function(err, balance) {

        let totalBalance = balance.available[0];
        vscode.window.showInformationMessage("Total Balance: $" + totalBalance.amount.toString());

    });

    dispose() {
        this.dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can make it with information windows but when I try to show amount value in status bar, I am getting an error like "statusbar undefined"

You haven't shown code for the status bar. Here is one that works:

```
const statusBarItem = vscode.window.createStatusBarItem(
  vscode.StatusBarAlignment.Left,
  0
);
statusBarItem.show();
statusBarItem.text = 'Hello world';
```